# What is the difference between "Large Matrix" and regular numeric matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, rstudio

When a relatively large matrix is created, Rstudio marks it as a Large Matrix in its environment window:

```
 x <- matrix(rnorm(10000 * 5000), ncol=5000)
 # Large matrix (50000000 elements, 381.5 Mb)
```

The mode() function as expected returns "numeric" for this object:

```
mode(x)
## [1] "numeric"
```

If however I run the following command:

```
mode(x) <- "numeric"
```

Rstudio changes "Large Matrix" into a regular numeric matrix:

```
# x:  num [1:10000, 1:5000]
```

So what is the difference between these 2 objects? Does this difference exist in Rstudio only or these two objects are different in R as well?

Answer (score 1):

In my understanding, "Large Matrix" and `matrix` is the same matrix object. What matters is how these objects are *displayed* in the global environment in RStudio.

RStudio also distinguishes between vectors and large vectors. Consider the following vector:

```
n <- 256
v1 <- rnorm(n*n-5)
```

This vector is listed  as a large vector. Now, let's decrease its size by one:

```
v2 <- rnorm(n*n-6)
```

Suddenly, it becomes a normal vector. The structure of both objects is the same (which can be verified by running `str`). So is their class and storage mode. What is different then? Notice that the size of `v2` in memory is exactly 512 Kb.

```
lobstr::obj_size(v2)
>524,288 B # or exactly 512 kB
```

The size of `v1` is slightly greater:

```
lobstr::obj_size(v1)
>524,296 B # or 512.0078125 KB
```

As far as I understand (correct me if I am wrong), for mere convenience RStudio displays objects that are greater than 512 kB differently.